Matrix with when when job depth is 3
For our GitHub Actions pipeline we want to run tests, if tests fail we want to rerun the test x amount of times (on custom infra), if the reruns of the tests are finished we want an analyze step. We already have the first tests in the following jobs: first-tests, first-tests-results
I created a matrix like the following to rerun the tests:
rerun-matrix:
  runs-on: ${{inputs.runner-tag}}
  strategy:
    matrix:
      reruns: [1, 2, 3]
  steps:
    - to be filled in

The part I want to repeat, note it used needs and if
rerun-failed-test:
  name: Rerun test run 
  needs: [first-tests, first-tests-results]
  if: failure() && needs.first-tests-results.result == 'failure'  && needs.first-tests.result == 'success'          
  runs-on: ${{inputs.runner-tag}}
  outputs:
    test-id: ${{steps.test.outputs.test-id}}
  steps:
    - name: test
      id: test
      uses: somedir/test@v1.0.0
      with:
        failed_test_id: ${{ needs.first-tests.outputs.test-id }}

rerun-test-result:
  name: Parse and analyze test results of rerun
  needs: [rerun-failed-test]
  if: failure() && needs.rerun-failed-test.result == 'success'  
  runs-on: ${{inputs.runner-tag}}
  steps:
    - name: parse-test-result
      id: parse-test-result
      uses: somedir/test-analyze-results@v1.0.0
      with:
        test-id: ${{ needs.rerun-failed-test.outputs.test-id }}

However the matrix expects steps/actions, and as far as I'm aware I cannot use the needs option I want to use. Because of the depth limit of 3 we can not use a workflow in the matrix.
We can also not create a separate workflow with the logic, as our workflow depth is already 3 and that would exceed the limit. This is already annoying because we also wanted to reuse the first test steps (test, analyze results) which we now have to create duplicate code for.
We want to make the amount of reruns dynamic, e.g. in the future we might need 99 reruns, or just 1. We do not want to repeat the code that is written.
How can we repeat the needed jobs given they have a needs/if condition?
